# Android simple method doesn't work on fragment destroys

Tags: android

I have simple method as:

```
private void resetView() {
    Log.e("RESET VIEW", "");
    params = robot_commands.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 0;
    robot_commands.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

and I want to do that on this methods or when fragment doesn't visible:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    resetView();
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    resetView();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But `resetView()` doesn't work.

Comment: how u know  `resetView ` method not working?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes that doesnt work for me, i cant get log result or debug that

Comment: Put the `resetView` in your `onCreateView` function first to check if its working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put your method into the `onPause()`

The reason is after ondestroy() called there is no guarantee that your method is called specially your method is time consuming.

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy Are you sure that resetView() is working perfectly.Try to just log on onPause()

Comment: yes i'm sure, nested `Log` into that not working too

Comment: So are you saying like that your overridden method onPause is not working.